# Do functions keep track of their inner variables?

Tags: python, variables, scope

I'm a bit confused about function variable scope, sometimes the function keeps track of its local variables so that if it's called again it recalls the previous values of the variables - and other times it doesn't keep track of the values.

In the following code, the function keeps track of the `mylist` and appends to it at every call.

```
def test(mylist=[]):
    mylist.append(1)
    print (mylist)

test()
test()
test()
```

The output:

```
[1]
[1, 1]
[1, 1, 1]
```

While in the following code, `x` is set to zero each time the function is called.

```
def test(x=0):
    x+=1
    print (x)

test()
test()
test()
```

The output:

```
1
1
1
```

What is the explanation of this behavior?

Also, is there a way to take a look at the current values of variables inside the functions from outside?

**[Update]**

After comments, I now understand why `mylist` is updated, but what about `x` in the second case? why is it not updated? is it because `x` is immutable while `mylist` is mutable?

Comment: Functions don't track values from one call to the next. What's happening in the first one is a quirk of default arguments that is heavily recommended to avoid using unless you have a really good reason, as per @0x5453's link.

Answer (score 1):

It's not `mylist` that's kept between invocations of the function, but rather the default value `[]`, which is a single anonymous array that's assigned by reference to `mylist` each time.

Appending to `mylist` of course appends to the array that it refers to.

In the first case, x contains a reference to an array, and when you "add to x" you modify *that* array.
In the second case, x simply contains a number `0`, and when you "add to x", you change what x contains.

The key point is that the expression for the default parameter value is evaluated only once, and re-used between calls to the function.

Welcome to Python :-(

Comment: So, why x is not updated in the second case?

Comment: In the first case, x contains a reference to an array, and when you "add to x" you modify _that_ array.
In the second case, x simply contains a number `0`, and when you "add to x", you change what x contains.